# Spring Batch job fails after inserting 13000 items

Tags: mysql, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am running spring batch job but it processes and inserts around 13000 elements and after that fails with following stack trace

```
ERROR: org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:358)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:203)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:308)
    ... 36 more
```

Batch job xml has following configuration

```
<bean id="customWriter" class="com.validatemyproduct.jobs.randomjob.CustomItemWriter" /> 

<job id="simpleRandomJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <!-- job-repository="jobRepository" parent="simpleJob"> -->
 <step id="step1">
  <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="customReader" processor="customProcessor" writer="customWriter" commit-interval="1"/>
  </tasklet>
 </step>
 <listeners>
    <listener ref="myListener"/>
</listeners>
</job>  


<bean id="myListener" class="com.validatemyproduct.jobs.randomjob.joblistener.MyJobExecutionListener"/>

<bean id="simpleJob" class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob" abstract="true">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
<batch:job-repository id="jobRepository"
data-source="dataSource"
transaction-manager="transactionManager"
isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE"
table-prefix="BATCH_"
max-varchar-length="1000"/>

<bean id="jobRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
```

```
<!-- 4.3. Configuring a JobLauncher asynchronously -->
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
```

What could be the possible mistake on my part
although it runs fine for small list (ex 100)
but fails when it has to process millions of records .

Comment: Maybe MySQL's `max_packet_size`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/communication-errors.html

Comment: Thank you ! I found the solution it was because i had not used connection pooling . Connection resources were created every time a single operation was performed . Thanks BTW .